# Animate css progress bar without jumping between updates?

Tags: html, css, video, progress-bar, html5-video

I'm using this on my site …

```
<progress id='video-progress' min='0' max='100' value=''></progress>
```

This is the entire styling of the element …

```
#video-progress {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:3px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

So all it does is move from 0 to 100% screen width on the bottom of the page.
The progress bar is updated via Javascript.

However since my video is only 30 seconds long, the single steps of updates are executed as "jumps" for the progress bar. **So there is no smooth motion of the bar.**

Any idea how I could animate the progress bar or **smooth** it between the updated steps?

UPDATE:

JavaScript …

```
function updateProgressBar() {
    var progressBar = document.getElementById('video-progress');
    var percentage = Math.floor((100 / fmVideo.duration) * fmVideo.currentTime);
    progressBar.value = percentage;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the JavaScript code as well?

Comment: Could you add the JavaScript also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could animate it by incrementing its `value` every `15 millisecond` using `setInterval` and stop incrementing if the `value` is greater than `percentage` using `clearInterval`.

This code extracts the current `value` and increments it until it reaches the `percentage` value.

**Note:** `percentage` is manually set to `70`.

```js
var progressBar = document.getElementById('video-progress');

function updateProgressBar() {
  var percentage = 70;
  var curr = progressBar.value;
  var update = setInterval(function() {
    if (curr > percentage) {
      clearInterval(update);
    }
    progressBar.value = curr++;
  }, 15)
}

updateProgressBar();
```

```css
#video-progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<progress id='video-progress' min='0' max='100' value=''></progress>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to be done with transition: width ... ?

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me!

```
function smoothProgress(e) {
    var id = $("#"+e.data.id),
        dur = 5000,
        seq = 100,
        max = parseInt( id.attr("max"), 10),
        chunk = max / dur * seq,
        loop = setInterval(function() {
        if( id.val() < max )
            id.val( id.val() + chunk );
        else
            clearInterval(loop);
        }
    }, seq);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#launch").on("click", {id: $("progress").attr("id")}, smoothProgress);
});
```

Of course, you can adjust the `dur` parameter or retrieve it dynamically based on your video's duration, as well as the `seq` parameter (the lower, the smoother).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/e4cevLu2/) for demo.